# C++ Hex to Int using Stringstream

Tags: c++, binary, hex, stringstream

I have a function that prints out the binary of int inputs.

When I have a hex in string form, I call the function using:

```
    int num = 0;
    stringstream << "0xabcd123";
    stringstream >> num;  //num becomes the decimal representation of the above hex.
    outputBinary(num);
```

Works perfectly.

However,

```
    int num = 0;
    stringstream << "0xabcd1234"; //fully filled hex value.
    stringstream >> num;  //num remains at 0.
    outputBinary(num);
```

Could it be that a fully filled hex value cause stringstream to overflow when converting from hex string to "num"?

Comment: Your two snippets of code are identical (and your probably nee to show `outputBinary`, two)

Comment: Tried `unsigned num;  stringstream >> num;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is out of range.  According to the Standard, the string is parsed using `strtoll`... the value does fit in `long long` and is interpreted as positive.  Then it checks whether it can fit in the type provided (`int`).  But no, it can't, assuming your compiler has 32-bit `int`.

Writing

```
int num = 0xabcd1234;
```

in your source code would be trouble as well, because the literal will be given type `unsigned int`, and the implicit conversion to `signed int` is out of range, resulting in implementation-defined behavior.