# Any C++ simple standard function to convert 32 bit signed 2's complement hexadecimal string to decimal?

Tags: c++

I got string "FFFF6472", and want to convert it to -39822 like below:

```
std::string hex = "FFFF6472";
int dec = hex_to_int(hex);
printf("%d", dec); // -39822
```

Are there any supported functions like 'hex_to_int' in standard library?

Comment: `stoi`/`stol` accepts a `base` parameter, for which you can pass 16: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol.

Comment: See also [C++ Hex to Int using Stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310530/c-hex-to-int-using-stringstream)

Comment: Thx guys. These answers also helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: Also, you can take a look at `std::from_chars` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).